# Problem with extending custom TYPO3 9.5 extension - I can't add action in controller

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

In FE I have an error

```
(1/1) #1186669086 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception\NoSuchActionException
An action "showcandidateAction" does not exist in controller "Myvendor\VvApplicationform\Controller\ApplicationformController".
```

In ext_localconf.php I have a this

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
 'Myvendor.VvApplicationform',
    'Candidateform',
    array(
        'Applicationform' => 'showcandidate',
    ),
    array(
        'Applicationform' => 'showcandidate',
    )
);
```

When I change the action in ext_localconf.php to another - I see correct form in FE.
In controller - applicationform/Classes/Controller/ApplicationformController.php:

```
/*
  * @param \Myvendor\VvApplicationform\Domain\Model\CandidateApplication $application
  * @return void
  */
public function showcandidateAction(\Myvendor\VvApplicationform\Domain\Model\CandidateApplication $application = null) {
...
}
```

After changes I clear all cache and Dump autoload. But still have an error in FE.
Of course I have a template here `'applicationform/Resources/Private/Templates/Applicationform/Showcandidate.html'`

UP1 I forgot to notify that I'm using TYPO3 9.5

UP2 This is a registerPlugin in ext_tables.php: `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin('Myvendor.VvApplicationform', 'Candidateform', 'Candidate Form');`

UP3 - directory of this ext named vv_applicationform. I've updated wrong names in initial post.
This is ApplicationformController.php

```
 namespace Myvendor\VvApplicationform\Controller;
    /**
 * Class ApplicationformController
 *
 * @package Myvendor\VvApplicationform\Controller
 */
class ApplicationformController extends ActionController
{
```

Comment: Can you add the "namespace" and the "class" definition line of your action controller ?

Comment: @StefanBürk Please find UP3 in the first post, I've added info about this. Thanks in advance

Comment: If files are at the write place and no issues with camelcases etc. try to deactivate and re- activate extension in backend modul called extension.

Answer (score 0):

You've to configure your plugin differently:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
 'applicationform',
    'Candidateform',
    array(
        Myvendor\Applicationform\Controller\ApplicationformController::class => 'showcandidate',
    ),
    array(
        Myvendor\Applicationform\Controller\ApplicationformController::class => 'showcandidate',
    )
);
```

A description about it you find here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/FrontendPlugins.html#id2

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to notify that I'm using TYPO3 9.5.

Comment: Yes.
Like that:
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin('Myvendor.applicationform', 'Candidateform', 'Candidate Form');

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in CamelCase-writing.

Extensionfolder: vv_applicationform
Namespace: Myvendor\VvApplicationform...

And then in ext_localconf.php is the bug. Replace 'Myvendor.Vvapplicationform' with 'Myvendor.VvApplicationform'

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
 'Myvendor.VvApplicationform',
    'Candidateform',
    [
        'Applicationform' => 'showcandidate',
    ],
    [
        'Applicationform' => 'showcandidate',
    ]
);
```

From ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(...)

```
 * @param string $extensionName The extension name (in UpperCamelCase) or the extension key (in lower_underscore)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I already have correct name 'Myvendor.VvApplicationform' in ext_localconf.php 
But problem in something else

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this issue.
I was a stupid error - backup copy directory inside Controller directory.
This is my tree:

```
-Controller
--Mybak_folder
  -ApplicationformController.php
--ApplicationformController.php
```

When I deleted directory "Mybak_folder" and Dump autoload from TYPO3 Maintenance I solved this problem!..
Thanks for all who trying to help